# duvida com logica de porcentagens

Tags: porcentagem, matemática

Olá, tenho uma dúvida em um problema de porcentagens...
Ana ganha R$5.000,00 e Julio ganha R$9.0000,00. Eles tem em comum uma dívida de R$6.000,00 e querem pagar esse valor proporcionalmente ao valor que recebem. Quanto é a parte devida a cada um?

Estou fazendo o seguinte cálculo:

```
9000 -------- 100%
5000 -------- X%

500000 = 9000X
X = 500000/9000
X = 55.55%
```

Ou seja, Ana ganha 45% a menos que Júlio, logo ela deveria pagar 45% de R$6.000,00.

Isso não tá fazendo muito sentido pra mim. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Isso não é uma pergunta sobre programação ou sobre qualquer coisa relacionada a TI. É apenas uma pergunta sobre matemática. Por isso, acho que esta pergunta está fora do escopo do site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Primeiro é necessário calcular a soma de ambos os rendimentos, ou seja, 9000+5000=14000 reais.

Os percentuais de rendimento de cada um é:
Ana 5000x100/14000=35.71%
Júlio 9000x100/14000=64.29%

Para pagarem proporcionalmente, o cálculo é o seguinte:

Ana 0,3571x6000=2142.60 Reais
Júlio 0.6429x6000=3857.40 Reais